# Joomla editor post content via JQuery

Tags: jquery, post, joomla, text-editor

I trying to create my component which include Joomla CodeMirror plugin.
I filled textarea with my text and now I want to get that text from JQuery for send to another place.

```
    jQuery("#button").click(function(event){
        jQuery('#spinner').show();
        var code = jQuery('#texteditorarea').html();

        jQuery.post("index.php?option=com_one&view=One&format=raw",
        {
            source:code
        },
        function(data) {
            jQuery('#spinner').hide();
            jQuery("#result").hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
```

Here I have a problem when I changed text in Joomla editor field (on my page). When I click on my button after change, in this code I do not see any changes. 
With

```
var code = jQuery('#texteditorarea').html();
```

I always get initial text.

How can I catch current text in Joomla editor text filed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer

Instead:

```
var code = jQuery('#texteditorarea').html();
```

Use:

```
var code = Joomla.editors.instances['texteditorarea'].getCode();
```